# What c compiler does nim use to make exe file?

Tags: c, nim-lang, transpiler

Should I install gcc or other c compiler after installing nim to compile my code to an executable file or it contains? If it contains, which c compiler it uses? gcc, tcc, clang etc.

Don't get me wrong, I dont want to convert my nim code to c.

I just want to know what compiler it uses after translating nim to c to make mashin code.

I don't want to install it before I'm getting sure, how it really works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the install on Linux/Unix/macOS page](https://nim-lang.org/install_unix.html):

> The Nim compiler **needs a C compiler** in order to compile software. **You must install this separately** and ensure that it is in your `PATH`.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So yes you need to install a C compiler for it to work. There's no mention about *which* compiler to install or use, so it probably uses the common alias `cc` to build the C source.

You can install the default compiler for your platform and it should work.

---

[The Windows download page](https://nim-lang.org/install_windows.html) recommends MinGW, which is GCC.

Comment: On Linux the common choice is GCC or Clang, on Mac it's Clang I believe. But pretty much any C compiler should work. I believe the installer for Windows also installs MinGW automatically.